# Is there a way to iterate over sessions in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azureservicebus

Is there a way to get the list of available sessions or a list of sessions with messages in Azure Service Bus?

Comment: No AFAIK. In general, ASB is not intended to be used as a database for querying.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you could not do that in Azure Service Bus, it is not to be used for such query like a database.

Answer (score 0):

*I agree with other answers & comments that SB shouldn't be used as a database and I found an alternate way to implement it but to answer this question.*

Using C# sdk, we could achieve this by repeatedly calling `AcceptNextSessionAsync` until you hit a `ServiceTimeout` exception (essentially locking all available sessions).

Note: This program should be the only subscriber to the topic/queue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this is late, but there is a way to do this with the C# [legacy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) SDK.

```cs
MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(<ConnectionString>);
QueueClient queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(<QueuePath>, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
var sessions = client.GetMessageSessions(); // This gets the available sessions
```

However, with the latest SDK, this is not possible. A workaround could be to store a list of session-id using a loop, and stop when it's repeated.

```cs
ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(<ConnectionString>);
List<string> messageIdList = new List<string>();
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceBusSessionReceiver receiver = await client.AcceptNextSessionAsync(<QueueName>);
        if (messageIdList.Contains(receiver.SessionId))
            break;
        messageIdList.Add(receiver.SessionId);
    }
    catch
    {
        break; 
    }
}
```

As you have mentioned in your own answer, this may work for one consumer (you, in this case). And we're stopping at one point when we accept the already processed session, meaning the lock of that session expired and reached us back. A queue with a greater lock duration may be useful in this case. Please note this is a workaround.